# Parameter based reverse routing in scala play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In my *.scala.html* file I invoke a reverse route quite simply -

```
@(query: String)( implicit request: RequestHeader )

<script type="text/javascript">
function createWebsocket(){
    var socket = new WebSocket("@routes.module.live3( query ).webSocketURL()")
    ...
}
</script>
```

Now, as my application evolves the number of routes (like the *route.module.live3* above) will increase. So I want to pass the route itself as a parameter (along with the parameter query above). Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: So, instead of using the reverse routing as above, you want to pass a String that is the URL generated by the reverse routing to your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could generate the absolute URLs in the controllers and then pass them to the views:

```
val url = routes.module.live3(query).absoluteURL()
```

Then in order to get Websocket URLs or HTTPS URLs you could use `.webSocketURL()` `.absoluteURL(true)` instead of just `.absoluteURL()`.

Comment: it was right in front of me... dont know what I was thinking! :-)